# How to handle network error in Passport authentication using Express and React

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

I have an express server running to enable user authentication using passport. I get the user information when running the express URL but I'm not able to fetch the user object from my react application using axios. My React app says Network error.

I tried using

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors())
```

Express app.js (Running as `http://localhost:3000`)

```
var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
  discoveryURL : discovery_url,
  clientID : client_id,
  clientSecret : client_secret,
  callbackURL : callback_url,
  skipUserProfile : true
},
  function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        done(null, profile);
    })
  }
)

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(Strategy); 
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
              req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    return next();
  }
}

app.get('/user', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.user);
});
```

My express app running on port 3000 so I'm able to see the user object while visiting http://localhost:3000/user

But I'm receiving network error when I try to access this in my react application.

My react component is

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class UserInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      userinfo: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/user')
    .then(res => {
      const userinfo = res.data;
      this.setState({ userinfo });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Fetch error", err)
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log("User Info", userinfo);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        Name: {this.state.userinfo.name}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Error is

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Fetch error Error: Network Error
```

****Edit after changing axios****

When I checked the response in mozilla developer tools and inspected the network. The API was not giving any response Then Changed the axios to

```
axios('https://localhost:3000/hello', { 
      method: 'get',
      withCredentials : true 
    })
```

Then the newtwok in the developer tool gave response and the react application crashed saying `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error`

Comment: Show the error please

Comment: I had edited with the error message @LuisMendes535

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are placing the `cors` middleware before the routes.

```
app.use(cors());

...

app.get('/user', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.user);
});
```

Also the url used in react app is using `https` scheme.

Comment: Yes I have added the cors before route.. that is not the cause.

Comment: In the react app, the url is using `https` scheme. Is that a typo or is localhost running on ssl?

Comment: That was a typo ... Sorry for confusing you .. I will edit and remove it, that was also not the cause ..

Comment: I have an another thought that the authentication is happening from an external service provider rt - using passport. So that might give us the CORS issue as we cannot use CORS middleware in the authentication server